# How to UPDATE a column from a self join table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, self-join

I need to replace a column by a column from a self join table but I got an error. What should I do? Thanks!

```
UPDATE a
SET propertyaddress=COALESCE(a.propertyaddress,b.propertyaddress)
FROM Housing a
JOIN Housing b
  ON a.ParcelID=b.ParcelID
  AND a.uniqueid!=b.uniqueid
WHERE a.propertyaddress IS NULL);
```

ERROR:  relation "a" does not exist
LINE 32: UPDATE a
^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using the Microsoft-Syntax for UPDATE.
(and you don't need the `COALESCE()`, since `a.propertyaddress` is always NULL)

[Postgres documentation for UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

---

```
UPDATE Housing a
SET propertyaddress = b.propertyaddress
FROM Housing b
WHERE a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
  AND a.uniqueid <> b.uniqueid
  AND a.propertyaddress IS NULL
  ;
```

Comment: No need to use self join? Can I ask one more question? When to use SELF JOIN? Thanks! Much appreciated.

Comment: @JadeYoung  This is a self join.  It is just written in a different style than the MSSQL style.